# Is it true that a quasiconvex, increasing and continous function, is convex?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a **continuous** and **increasing** function.
Let $f$ be **quasiconvex**.
Let $f(0)=0$.

**Can we say that $f(x)$ is convex ?**

If yes, how do we prove it ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: What do "quasiconvex" and "increasing" mean? (This is probably standard notation, but not for me at least.)

Comment: Increasing just means that f(x)>=f(y) implies x>=y; whereas quasiconvex implies a harder def. Unfortunately I haven't fully understood it. It means that if f(x)>=f(y), then f(ax + (1-a)y) >= f(y). Sorry for the typos in Latek, I'm new to this language

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro see [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=quasiconvex), for example (the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) is fairly thorough)

Comment: What does $x\ge y$ mean when $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Every continuous increasing function on the real line is quasiconvex, but not every such function is convex, so there are tons of counterexamples, e.g., $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: What happens if I impose n>1, can you still find counterexamples ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Then you first have to define what increasing means for functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., with respect to what kind of (partial) order on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But with just about any definition, you can get basically the same counterexample by defining $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1^3$.

Comment: Yes, right answer.

Comment: Dear Lukas Geyer, I am waiting to your comments in my question. Thank you for your kind help. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220706/constructing-a-quasiconvex-function